# Use of Greater Than Symbol in XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I had created the xml document with xml version="1.0".

In that document I need to use the greater than symbol `>` and less than symbol `<`.

How should I include those symbols? It's not working.

`&gt;` and `&lt;` are not working for me.

Is there any special encoder for this?

Comment: You say that > is not working for you? Can you post some of your code?

Comment: "Not working" in what way? Be more specific (error message, etc) because > and < are indeed one of the two propers methods.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 116):

You need the [Character Entity References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

`< = &lt;`

`> = &gt;`

Comment: so, i just put `&lt;` where I want the `<` to be?

Comment: I don't believe `&le;` and `&ge;` are valid in xml. Just `&lt;` and `&gt;`. If you need an 'equals', simply append a `=` character.

Answer (score 24):

You can try to use [CDATA](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_cdata.asp) to put all your symbols that don't work.

An example of something that will work in XML:

```
<![CDATA[
function matchwo(a,b) {
    if (a < b && a < 0) {
        return 1;
   } else {
       return 0;
   }
}
]]>
```

And of course you can use `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: you'll also have to put in javascript comments so you won't get a syntax error. /* <![CDATA[ */ ... /* ]]> */

Comment: no, no you don't - the *value-of* of the node will not include the CDATA markup - try it

Answer (score 18):

Use `&gt;` and `&lt;` for 'greater-than' and 'less-than' respectively