# What is the equivalent of 'greater-than-equal-to' or 'less-than-equal-to' in XML?

Tags: xml, escaping

I found this [Use of Greater Than Symbol in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330725/use-of-greater-than-symbol-in-xml) where the answer is to use the following for 'greater-than' and 'less-than' respectively:

```xml
&gt; and &lt;
```

However, what should we use for 'greater-than-equal-to' and 'less-than-equal-to' ?

I already tried the following but it didn't work for me.

```xml
&ge; and &le; and &gte; and &lte;
```

Comment: What characters/strings are you trying to escape? `<=` and `>=` or `≥` and `≤`?

Comment: I need to use it in a xslt file. So, I am looking for the first set (<= and >=)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125180/what-is-the-equivalent-of-greater-than-equal-to-or-less-than-equal-to-in-xml#comment67525397_40125180) by [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba):

> Just use `&gt;= and &lt;=`.
> - Oct 19, 2016 at 9:46

Answer (score 6):

As XML is Unicode-aware, it prefers the raw characters ≤ and ≥. Alternatively, `&#x2264;` and `&#x2265;` are the hexadecimal character references to ≤ and ≥.

Comment: This answer is way better for presentation. The & codes work in XAML as well.

Answer (score 1):

For using it in programming languages I chose using Unicode:

**Java**
"\u2264" for ≤
"\u2265" for ≥

**Python**
u"\u2264" for ≤
u"\u2265" for ≥