# XML - If greater / smaller then number

Tags: xml, if-statement, conditional-statements

i'm coding for to an API (Allplan, it's a CAD programm) and got a problem:

Here is my code:

```
        <Parameter>

            <Name>Row2</Name>
            <Text>2.</Text>
            <ValueType>Row</ValueType>
            <Visible>anzahl == 1</Visible>

        </Parameter>
```

This works fine, but now i want to change == to >= like in python. But this wont work.

I tried to use:

```
        <Parameter>

            <Name>Row2</Name>
            <Text>2.</Text>
            <ValueType>Row</ValueType>
            <Visible>anzahl &smte; 1</Visible>

        </Parameter>
```

Is it even possible to get a condition check in XML?
The source code is coded in Python, but the UI in XML. So i dont have that much practise with XML.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add python code please.

Comment: You need to escape the closing angel bracket.  Try `&gt;=`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of Greater Than Symbol in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330725/use-of-greater-than-symbol-in-xml) AND/OR [What is the equivalent of 'greater-than-equal-to' or 'less-than-equal-to' in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125180/what-is-the-equivalent-of-greater-than-equal-to-or-less-than-equal-to-in-xml)

Answer (score 1):

> This works fine, but now i want to change == to >= like in python. But this wont work.

What do you mean when you say "*this wont work*"? `<Visible>anzahl >= 1</Visible>` is well-formed XML so is there an error or display issue or something?

Does the API have documentation? Maybe that will tell you its requirements for the XML that you send it.

For `<=` the `<` would need to be escaped to be well-formed XML. An alternative is to use `CDATA` but I'm not sure if the API you're using can handle it. Example...

```xml
<Visible><![CDATA[anzahl <= 1]]></Visible>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question about XML per se, it's a question about a specific XML vocabulary. As far as XML is concerned, `anzahl == 1` is just a character string. It's interpreted by the application (Allplan) and you need to consult the documentation for that application to see how a different condition should be entered.

However, you should be aware that the `<` and `>` characters need special treatment: they are typically escaped as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

The entity `&smte;` has two problems. The first problem is that as an entity it's defined in HTML but not in XML, unless you add a DTD to your document that defines it. In HTML it maps to the character `⪬`, Unicode 10924. The second problem is that I think it's unlikely that Allplan uses the character U+10924 in its API - though I don't know the API so I might be wrong on this.

Comment: Can you add a source for this statement: "The first problem is that as an entity it's defined in HTML" ?

Comment: @Luuk:  See WHATWG's [HTML
Living Standard — Last Updated 20 December 2023; 13.5 Named character references](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#entity-smte).

Comment: ok, sorry, never seen that **_living_** character before (But now I can find it too: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2aac/index.htm ) But is that _really_ used? :  see: [&smte; vs. &lte;](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=593231940&q=%26smte;+vs.+%26lte;&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYktLBnqWDAxUPiv0HHVuqDWwQvgUoAXoECA0QAw&cshid=1703323602771819&biw=1373&bih=1147&dpr=1) which is not found...

Comment: @Luuk: Most programming languages would use `<=`, which would be represented   in an XML file as `&lt;=`, but you'd have to check Allplan's documentation to see what they use.

Answer (score 1):

The text into the xml `<Visible>` tag can converted, but this doesn’t calculate true or false. For such a condition check you can use `operator`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
import operator

xml_1="""
<Parameter>
  <Name>Row2</Name>
  <Text>2.</Text>
  <ValueType>Row</ValueType>
  <Visible>anzahl == 1</Visible>
</Parameter>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml_1)

def condition_check(value, node):
    # value must int or float
    check = node.text.split()
    check[0] = value
    ope = check[1]
    comp = float(check[2])
    ops = { ope: operator.ge}
    return ops[ope](check[0], comp)
    
def test_condition_change(node):
    # xml string manipulation
    new = re.sub('==', '>=', node.text)
    node.text = new
    return node

con = root.find('.//Visible')
new = test_condition_change(con)
    
ET.indent(root, space="  ")
ET.dump(root)

# test if 25 > or equal value in xml
test_boolean = condition_check(25, new)
print("Test:", test_boolean)
```

This gives you:

```
<Parameter>
  <Name>Row2</Name>
  <Text>2.</Text>
  <ValueType>Row</ValueType>
  <Visible>anzahl &gt;= 1</Visible>
</Parameter>
Test: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python expressions inside the `<Visible>` and in the `<Enable>` tags of a parameter in an Allplan .pyp file (Allplan 2024). In your case "anzahl" needs to be a constant or the name of another parameter which returns an integer value inside your .pyp file. In your case it unclear where “anzahl” is derived from. It should be possible like described below.

You can change:

```
<Visible>anzahl == 1</Visible>
```

into:

```
<Visible>anzahl >= 1</Visible>
```

This is documented in the Allplan Python Api documentation (although it might be a bit hidden). You can find the information on the following page: https://pythonparts.allplan.com/2024/manual/features/dynamic_property_palette/

You can find more examples of this when you open the Visibility.pyp file you can find in the following folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\Nemetschek\Allplan\2024\Etc\Examples\PythonParts\PaletteExamples\Visibility.pyp
```

The Allplan Pythonpart framework supports these kind of operations, so it is not necessary to perform any XML operations to get this working. You can find more info on how the property palette works here: https://pythonparts.allplan.com/2024/manual/key_components/

The getting started page of the documentation will guide you to the examples which are installed allongside Allplan: https://pythonparts.allplan.com/2024/getting_started/